# How to write SQL to JPQL

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpql, translate

I am learning JPQL, but I think this is very complex, I am good sql server user, but  I cant translate this, help please.

```
SELECT * FROM liquidacion AS l INNER JOIN tipo_plan AS tp ON l.plan_id = tp.id 
WHERE ((tp.nombre like @nombrePlan OR @nombrePlan IS NULL ) AND 
    (tp.id_ips = @idPlanIps OR @idPlanIps IS NULL) AND
    (l.periodo = @periodo OR @periodo IS NULL))
```

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to switch " * " to "l", in front of parameter names you should use " : " and instead of name tables you'll have the name of the class that represents the entity that you're using. 
So in the end you'll have something like: 
`SELECT l FROM Liquidacion AS l INNER JOIN TipoPlan AS tp ON l.plan_id = tp.id 
WHERE ((tp.nombre like :nombrePlan OR :nombrePlan IS NULL ) AND 
    (tp.id_ips = :idPlanIps OR :idPlanIps IS NULL) AND
    (l.periodo = :periodo OR :periodo IS NULL))`